# Categorisation of spiritual discipline (upaayas/means of approach)?

Tags: spirituality

The path of spirituality needs a lot of discipline and inner instinct and belief for that parmatma who is highest realisation. My question is, is there any categorisation of spiritual discipline(upaayas: "means of approach")?